# how to fix api request returns 426

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers

I have a problem that when I send a request using requests for my api , I receive a 426 response which means: "protocol Upgrade Required"
My code:

```
headers= {
'user-agent ': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}


req = requests.get(myApi, headers=headers, auth=user_name_password)
print(req.status_code)
```

the result:
426

---

When I try to put the api on the browser , i give the username and password have a required result
So, I think that it is the api needs to be updated.

when I copy as curl , I take all of the header and try to put in my headers but again I have 426 error.

Comment: The problem is possibly in your API code. 426 is really quite rare and it's not clear what it means here... but you insinuate that you made that API

Comment: Remember that status codes beginning with a 4 are _client_ errors, not server ones. You've not given enough useful information for anyone to help you - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

> So, I think that it is the api needs to be updated.

No this is not what [426](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426) means, it is

> client error response code indicates that the server refuses to perform the request using the current protocol but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different protocol.

So **server** is informing that **client** needs upgrade, details are given in `Upgrade` response header, to reveal its' value add

```
print(r.headers['Upgrade'])
```

after last line of your code

Comment: In my case Axios was throwing, so I could never get the headers, but I managed to find them in the logs to work out what the issue was [needed a newer version of the LinkedIn API].